# On Android or iOS - how to approach the possibility of a service or app going into a broken state

Tags: iphone, android, ios, ipad, ios4

...and this broken state persisting until a device restart, since a naive attempt to restart an app would not work. Many users are not savvy enough to know how to terminate services/backgrounded apps. If the user can't (or doesn't 'need to') close apps, then what about restarting apps which have gone wrong? ( It can happen :) ) If my app goes wrong on someone's phone and they cannot easily restart the app without restarting the phone, that seems like a problem. I am aware that apps and services can be terminated by navigating system menus or double tapping the home button etc. but - many users are not aware of these features. For this reason I am thinking of adding an explicit close button to my app which will kill everything to the best of my ability, such that on a subsequent launch the program runs from the beginning again. I realise this is not the 'recommended' approach. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thoughts?

Don't do it. Instead you should put a FAQ entry on your apps website that says.

> Q: My app does not run anymore. HELP!
>
> A: First you should try to restart the app. If that doesn't work feel
>   free to contact me.
>
> Here is how you do this on the iPhone,
>   iPad or iPod.
>
> double press the home button. the
>   multi tasking bar appears.
>
> [ some screen shots ]
>
> long press the app icon and press the
>   little x that appears on the icon.
>
> [ more screenshots ]

If you want to put buttons for functions that are not obvious for many users you end up with a button for everything. And I (as somebody who knows every function) don't want a button cluttered user interface.

You would be surprised how many emails I get about "how can I zoom?" (A: Pinch your fingers) or "how do I delete an entry (in a tableview)" (A: Swipe your finger over the entry from left to right, and press the red delete button).

If I get an email about this I just point them to the faq which has some nice screenshots.

---

Btw, if the "broken state" happens so often that you would consider adding a special button I would check my code for bugs again.

Comment: Ok thanks. well I guess if there is a right answer then this it.

Comment: Ok thanks. well I guess if there is a right answer then this it. However, its a clunky process to close an app. I think users would like an easier way. They do appreciate the difference between closing and backgrounding. ie if I semi trust an app, then I am happy for it to run while I'm there looking at it, but not 24/7 with access to my network and whatever other privileges it has - possible on both droid and iphone. iphone does it better than the droid, but... Design flaw if you ask me. There should be a direct way to kill apps (I guess an X in the corner is too 1990s) Am I getting old?